# What is c# analog of C++ const reference return value

Tags: c#, c++, constants

I do write c++ accessor to class member as

```
SomeClass const& x() const { return m_x; }
```

It seems that the only protection of this sort in c# is to define property with private (or undefined) set. But this protects only against assignments not against manipulation of the some-class state.

Side note: c++ allows m_x to be deleted through const pointer - IMHO this is simply amazing oversight of standard bodies.

Comment: *"IMHO this is simply amazing oversight of standard bodies."* -. No, it's not. Even `const` objects need to be destroyed. Otherwise, how would you handle something like `void f() { Foo const foo; }`?

Comment: @Christian - I strongly disagree: compilers are smart enough to distinguish destruction of stack and class member objects from explicit calls to delete, there is no point to keep this gate wide open any longer.

Comment: But what would be the advantage of disallowing deletion via `const` pointers? It would be quite inconsistent with the rest of the language. If you are interested in this issue, google "delete pointer const" and look at all the Stackoverflow questions and answers. Even if you disagree with everyone else, it's hardly an "oversight".

Comment: @Christian. I am not trying to convince anybody, I am just stating my opinion. The advantage is detecting crashes at compile time. And I will read the relevant discussion thanks for pointing it.

Comment: Well, but deleting a `const` pointer isn't a crash. If it crashes with a `const` pointer, then it would also crash with a non-`const` one...

Comment: @Christian. Huh? In my world if something could not be deleted (e.g. class member) there are no non-const pointer to it. I would dare to say that in 99.9% of the code I am writing there are no non-const pointers to class members at all. It is that simple. It just a consequence of general discipline: object state changes only through meaningful api answering the question 'what did happen with the object?' vs. 'what did changed inside the object?'. BTW, the source of my question is that I would like to express the same discipline using c#.

Comment: The point is: there is a huge difference between changing an object's state and destroying an object. Destroying an object is *not* considered changing its state. Not in C++ and not in any other programming language I know.

Comment: I spent previous 20+ years working on a very big project with few thousands of developers. One of the things I learned in the process: If there is a window for a screw up, it will happen somewhere in the millions of the lines of code and once in 10 years it will be hit in the field. Possibility to call delete on a const pointer is a very wide window, that should be closed (IMHO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, with C# 7.2, you can use `ref readonly` for the same purpose. You can check more about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly). Check the third point.

Answer (score -1):

`const` in C++ doesn't protect against anything, you can cast it away without any issues.

And while C# doesn't have its equivalent, you *can* (and usually should) create real immutable classes. This puts the burden of `const`ness on the object returned where it belongs, and there's nothing you can do to "cast it away" (barring reflection).

Comment: *"`const` in C++ doesn't protect against anything, you can cast it away without any issues."* - C++ protects against Murphy, not against Machiavelli. Also, "without any issues" is wrong. You can easily get into undefined-behaviour territory via `const_cast`.

Comment: By the way... *Immutable in C# doesn't protect against anything, you can get it away via reflection without any issues.*

Comment: @blindy. I suppose the only way to have immutable class it to keep set properties private and to have all access functions to create return values on the fly from internal fields. Are there any other ways? Any published advice to follow?

Comment: @zzz777 If your properties return value types or immutable reference types, there's nothing you need to do, the user won't be able to modify any class state through those (well, they could if the value type held a reference to the original type and had access to mutable state of said type, but that's probably naughty).  The advice I'd offer is to make things immutable until they need to be mutable.

Comment: @kyle. I am sorry I am very new to c#, any pointers to general advice on how to make things immutable in c#?

Comment: Jon Skeet I believe has an entire library of immutable collection types. The gist of it is that you arrange your data in a functional way -- recursive, with each "node" holding data and an immutable pointer to the next element. "Mutating" the collection happens by copying the affected nodes with updated information (data/pointers).